# Trying to plot a circular barplot and get Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): hjust R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got an error in R, when tried to plot the circular barplot. This is the error - `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9):`

This is the structure of my data, just limited one:

```
structure(list(Symptom = c("Chills", "Chills", "Chills", "Cough", 
"Cough", "Cough"), Morbidity = c("Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", 
"Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", "Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", 
"Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", "Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", 
"Asthma (managed with an inhaler)"), Severity = c("Mild", "Moderate", 
"Severe", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), Count = c(264L, 53L, 
19L, 853L, 158L, 27L), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is what I how I tried to plot:

```
gather_divided <- data.frame(gather_divided)

gather_divided <- gather_divided %>%
  dplyr::select(Symptom, Morbidity, Severity, Count)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
nObsType <- nlevels(as.factor(gather_divided$Severity))

nObsType

to_add <- data.frame(matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(gather_divided$Morbidity)*nObsType, ncol(gather_divided)) )

colnames(to_add) <- colnames(gather_divided)

to_add$Morbidity <- rep(levels(gather_divided$Morbidity), each=empty_bar*nObsType )

gather_divided <- rbind(gather_divided, to_add)
gather_divided <- gather_divided %>% arrange(Morbidity, Symptom)

gather_divided$id <- rep( seq(1, nrow(gather_divided)/nObsType) , each=nObsType)

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- gather_divided %>% group_by(id, Symptom) %>% summarize(tot=sum(Count))
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- gather_divided %>% 
  group_by(Morbidity) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(gather_divided) +      

  # Add the stacked bar
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=Count, fill=Morbidity), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +

  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 500, xend = start, yend = 500), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 1000, xend = start, yend = 1000), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 1500, xend = start, yend = 1500), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 2000, xend = start, yend = 2000), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +


  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(gather_divided$id),5), y = c(0,  500, 1000,  1500,  2000), 
                    label = c("0",  "500", "1000", "1500",  "2000") , color="grey", size=6 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  ylim(-150,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +

  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+10, label= Symptom, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=Morbidity), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p
```

Did someone else tried to plot a circular marplot and faced the same issue? How to solve this issue? I am hoping to solve it. Thank you in advance for this.

Comment: That’s a lot of code for one problem, you might get more help if it was the smallest example that produces the error.

Comment: Could you make your question reproducible? [mre]

Comment: @MarkNeal and Peter - yes will update then